# Default image for ImageField in Django's ORM

Tags: django, django-orm

I'm using an `ImageField`  to store profile pictures on my model.

How do I set it to return a default image if no image is defined?

Answer (score 54):

I haven't tried this, but I'm relatively sure you can just set it as a default in your field.

```
pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='blah', default='path/to/my/default/image.jpg')
```

**EDIT**: Stupid StackOverflow won't let me comment on other people's answers, but that old snippet is not what you want.  I highly recommend [django-imagekit](http://bitbucket.org/jdriscoll/django-imagekit/wiki/Home) because it does tons of great image resizing and manipulation stuff very easily and cleanly.

Comment: Thanks for that link - looks like I'll be using that one down the road quite a bit.

Comment: @ericflo: Yeah, StackOverflow doesn't let you leave comment until you have 50 reputation, which is kind of annoying.

Comment: Actually this does work. Although perhaps not ideally... 

It behaves more like 'initial' than 'default' because it sets it to the default value on creation, but if you delete the image it does not set the value back to your default. 

So you might want to establish that default value as a constant someplace and set it back manually on delete.

Answer (score 19):

In models.py

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pic', default='default.jpg')
```

In settings.py add this:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Now, 
Manually, add an image with a name ''default' into the media folder.

Comment: Tried this, but nothing happened.

Comment: add `urlpatterns = [...] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` to your project's config/urls.py

Answer (score 11):

You could theoretically also use a function within your model definition. But I dont know whether this is good practice:

```
class Image(model.Models):
    image = ....

    def getImage(self):
        if not self.image:
            # depending on your template
            return default_path or default_image_object
```

and then within a template

```
   <img src="img.getImage" />
```

This gives you a great deal of flexibility for the future...

I'm using sorl for thumbnails generation with great success

Comment: Django already provides the url() method for this purpose: <img src="{{my_image.url}}">

Comment: True, but that wouldn't be able to supply a default url. You could create a custom `ImageField` class with a default url that gets returned if the image value is None.

Answer (score 7):

In your image field

```
field = models.ImageField(upload_to='xyz',default='default.jpg')
```

**Note : path should be inside MEDIA_ROOT.**

Answer (score 3):

you could try this in your template:

```
{% ifequal object.image None %}
    <img src="DEFAULT_IMAGE" />
{% else %}
    display image
{% endifequal %}
```

Comment: {% if obj.image %}display{% else %}<img src="default" />{% endif %} -- burn all {% ifequal %} tags!!

Comment: if you need it in all your views you could use an include, you could call it show_obj_image.html then use {% include "show_obj_image.html" %}

Answer (score 0):

You can provide an initial value with the 'default' parameter.
If there is already an image and you want to set it to default (instead of deleting it), you can try something like this:

```
DEFAULT = 'img/default.jpg'

class Example(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(default=DEFAULT)

    def set_image_to_default(self):
        self.image.delete(save=False)  # delete old image file
        self.image = DEFAULT
        self.save()
```

Then you can use `set_image_to_default()` instead of `image.delete()`, if you prefer the default.