# Django if image was not uploaded from admin add default image

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with Django image field. I should do image optional. If admin did not uploaded image django should add default image. How can do this?

Here is my code:

```
class News(models.Model):
news_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
news_text = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
news_short_text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
news_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='uimages', blank=True, null=True, default='')
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
news_logo = models.ImageField(
    upload_to='uimages', blank=True, null=True,
    default='path to image after your media folder')
```

add the image to the `default` section of the field

Comment: duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276887/default-image-for-imagefield-in-djangos-orm