# Django image field default static file

Tags: django

I was wondering if there is a way to use an static image file as a default for an ImageField?

I'm asking this because if you write something like this because first, I'm not able to upload media folder to my github repository because I store in there the user uploads, and the default file always be the same, so I want to serve the default from static but the user uploads from media directory.

If you use this:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to=/upload/folder/, default=/img/default.jpg, blank=True, null=True)
```

It will try to load the default image from the media directory.

Comment: Serving a default image file from the template in case your image field is null. Does not work for you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UPDATE:** This answer no longer works. Since version 1.9, Django removes the leading `/` from the file path to convert it to a relative path and then appends `/media/` to the path.

This change was made due to this ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25905

**Alternative**: I like [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1277903/1925257) as an alternative.

---

**Original answer:**

First, look at the these two paths:

```
/img/default.jpg    -   Absolute Path (starts with slash)
img/default.jpg     -   Relative Path (doesn't start with slash)
```

Now, if your default path is **absolute**, then Django will not convert the url to `/media/.../`. Django only converts the **relative paths**.

So, if you want to serve the default file from `static` folder, you can just set an absolute path to your file like - `/static/img/default.jpg`.

---

Extra:

You can even verify this. Django uses `urllib.parse.urljoin` to create the url. Try this:

```
>>> media_url = '/media/'
>>> abs_url   = '/img/default.jpg' # absolute url
>>> rel_url   = 'img/default.jpg'  # relative url

>>> from urllib.parse import urljoin # in Python 2: from urlparse import urljoin

>>> urljoin(media_url, abs_url) # test with absolute url
'/img/default.jpg'
>>> urljoin(media_url, rel_url) # test with relative url
'/media/img/default.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can define a method that points to the default image as;**

```
def upload_place_pics(instance, filename):
    return "place_pics/{user}/{filename}".format(user=instance.user, filename=filename)
def default_place_pics():
    return "place_pics/default_pic.jpg"

class Place(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    image = models.ImageField(default=default_place_pics, upload_to=upload_place_pics, null=True)
```

For more details on how to configure static files see the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/)