# How to set default image from not from media directory

Tags: django, default, imagefield

I don't know how to correctly set default path to none-media image.
I've tried to add `/`, but it doesn't help:

```
...
image = models.ImageField(...
                         default='/static/course_lesson/resources/images/default.jpg')
...
```

And in `HTML` page `image.url` looked as follows:

```
...
src="/media/static/course_lesson/resources/images/default.jpg"
...
```

Comment: That is logical, since `{% media ... %}`, in essence prepends the media root to the url.

Comment: My first reaction is to agree with @WillemVanOnsem but this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47723490/django-image-field-default-static-file?rq=1) question/answer implies (I think) your approach should work.  Try removing the single quotes

Comment: @HenryM , yes u're rigth, i've taken approach from this Q\A. But what do u mean when saying to remove single quotes?

Comment: `default=/static/course_lesson/resources/images/default.jpg`, not `default='/static/course_lesson/resources/images/default.jpg'`

Comment: @HenryM  , no that doesn't work - syntax error

Comment: Don't know then.  I liked the solution in the link I sent but I've never seen it done before.  I would always create a property within the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your model

```
def image_url (self):
    if self.image: return self.image.url
    else: return static("course_lesson/resources/images/default.jpg")
```

Then within template

`src="{{ object.image_url }}"`

Comment: That's work, but what if i want to refer to, app's static folder? I mean, eg: 
```course_lesson/static/course_lesson/resources/images/default.jpg```