# How to update ImageFiled with default image?

Tags: python, django

Hello I have a Profile model
When user creates a Profile, I set an default image to image1 field and then the user can upload a new image in place of default. Now I need to implement in views.py function the update of user uploaded images with default image again, so when the user need to delete an image I put default-image instead. 
Thanks a lot

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    image1 = models.ImageField(
        default='default-image.jpg', upload_to='images', blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def update_image1(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    image1 = request.user.profile.image1
```

Comment: do you want to reset image field value to default when user updates the field?

Comment: @sachinmathew,  yes

Answer (score 0):

Please see this question: [Default image for ImageField in Django's ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276887/default-image-for-imagefield-in-djangos-orm)

You need to add the path to your image as the default field:

```py
# myapp/models.py

...
class Profile(models.Model):
    image1 = models.ImageField(
        default='/path/to/default/image.jpg', upload_to='images', blank=True)
...
```

Where the root of the path is MEDIA_ROOT from your settings.py:

```py
# myproject/settings.py

...
MEDIA_ROOT = /path/to/media/root/
...
```

Answer (score 0):

**try**

```
from django.db.models.fields import NOT_PROVIDED

def formEdit(request, pk):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=pk)
    form  = YourProfileEditForm(request.POST or None, instance=obj)
    if form.is_valid():
        data = form.save(commit=False)
        for f in data._meta.fields:
            if f.default is not NOT_PROVIDED:  // if their is a default data for field
                print(f.default)
                setattr(data, f.name, f.default)

        data.save()
    return render(request, 'your_form_template.html', {'form': form})
```