# The 'user_image' attribute has no file associated with it | Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates

**CODE EXPLANATION**

In the following code, I had created a user dashboard which is displayed after user creates an account. On dashboard user image is also displayed whether user has uploaded or not.

If the user hasn't uploaded the image then a default image is displayed which can be seen below in the code.

But it is showing error if user has not uploaded image and works fine if user has uploaded an image.

**CODE**

dashboard.html

```
{% if values.user_image.url %}
   <a class="image" href="{% url 'setting' %}"><img src="{{ values.user_image.url }}" alt=""></a>
{% else %}
   <a class="image" href="{% url 'setting' %}"><img src="{% static 'img/user.png' %}" alt=""></a>
{% endif %}
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url = "login")
def user_home(request):
    if request.method == "GET":

        record = User.objects.get(email=request.user)
        wallet = Wallet.objects.get(user_id=request.user)
        walletbalance = wallet.wallet_balance

        context = {
            'walletbalance': walletbalance,
            'values': record,
        }

        return render(request, "userdashboard/index.html", context)
```

**ERROR**

```
ValueError at /user/setting
The 'user_image' attribute has no file associated with it.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/setting
Django Version: 3.2.6
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
The 'user_image' attribute has no file associated with it.
Exception Location: C:\Users\Qasim Iftikhar\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py, line 40, in _require_file
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Qasim Iftikhar\anaconda3\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Projects\\Barter',
 'C:\\Users\\Qasim Iftikhar\\anaconda3\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Qasim Iftikhar\\anaconda3\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Qasim Iftikhar\\anaconda3\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Qasim Iftikhar\\anaconda3',
 'C:\\Users\\Qasim Iftikhar\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Qasim Iftikhar\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\Qasim Iftikhar\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Qasim Iftikhar\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
Server time:    Sat, 25 Sep 2021 14:38:10 +0000
```

Comment: You can try to give the user_image a default file. Like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1276907/11607969

Answer (score 0):

You should check the truthiness of `values.user_image`, not `values.user_image.url`, since if no file is associated with it, the `.urls` attribute does not exist:

```
<a class="image" href="{% url 'setting' %}"><img src="{% if values.user_image %}{{ values.user_image.url }}{% else %}{% static 'img/user.png' %}{% endif %}" alt=""></a>
```